# Windows Server 2008 SBS incorrectly reports that external domains are internal

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I'm having a problem with some of our domains on our external web server, which appeared just a couple of days ago.

We have several domains on the external web server, but 3 of them are refusing to resolve from our internal network. From outside our internal network those 3 problem domains are fine.

The other domains that are on the same external server are resolving as they should.

Checked DNSWatch and all the domains are reporting the correct results.

So, I checked nslookup with the debug option and I notice that it says:

```
QUESTIONS:
   ourdomain.co.uk.wsd.local, type = AAAA, class = IN
```

With the apparent problem being that it thinks that this external domain is in fact an internal one.

Tried /flushdns on a workstation, and on the server itself. No dice. I don't think that this is often reported problem when not using forwarders for resolution because the symptoms don't fit.

Am I missing something really obvious?

**UPDATE**

This issue seems to have disappeared with no action taken. I'm still intrigued by this as it was originally working, then it stopped and then it started working again. Problems that disappear by themselves make me nervous. No telling when they will come back

Comment: It sounds like a hairpin NAT issue to me. Your nslookup looks normal, albeit with the rest of the answer omitted. Domain clients always append their primary DNS suffix to unqualified DNS queries, which then gets stripped off as the query progresses. If you issued a query without the trailing dot (domain.local instead of domain.local.) then what you're seeing is normal.

Comment: @joeqwerty - to be clear, the quoted text above is from a query for ourdomain.co.uk. The local part was added by the server for some reason.

Comment: What is the AD domain name? What is the DNS suffix of the server name?

Comment: @joeqwerty - The AD domain is called wsd, and I'm sorry, which part is the DNS suffix?

Comment: If the AD domain FQDN was wsd.domain.local, for example, then the DNS suffix would be domain.local. I guess what I'm asking is what is the FQDN of the server?

Answer (score 0):

There's enough information missing* to make it somewhat of a puzzle, but I can make an educated guess that you're using split horizon DNS and there are A records for your external websites on your public DNS server(s) and your internal SBS machine.

Simply open up your DNS console on SBS and make A records for those three domains and point them to the associated external IP address for the websites. I suspect that perhaps the external web server has been at one time joined to the domain, and that could be why there are `.local` records for at least one of your websites already in your AD integrated DNS zone.

While you're in the DNS console, check the sanity of the included records. Compare the records with the computers joined to the domain and see if there are any stale records. See if any computers need to be removed from the domain gracefully, or have been removed physically and you simply need to delete the computer object. Consider turning on aging and scavenging in the DNS, once you're thoroughly aware of what that will do.

*(questions about hairpin NAT, external server domain membership, virtual hosts, VPN tunnels, and IPv6 have been excluded for brevity, your mileage may vary, no guarantee of success is issued or implied)